# xCode vs Android SDK vs Adobe Flex

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex

I am going to develop an application which will be cross platform and it will be released for IOS and Android.

My App will be using network connectivity and communicate with the server and it has to be fast, reliable and responsive.

So my Question is: If i choose Adobe Flex to build that app for IOS and Android, So will there be any performance issues?

If no then why people use xcode or android sdk?
What are the disadvantages of using Adobe Flex over xCode and Andoid SDK?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you use a cross-platform "write it once and build for many platforms" tool you likely will give up the ability to take advantage of some (or all?) device- or platform-specific features. You are, in effect, choosing a lowest common denominator sort of solution. That is to say, you have available to you only the platform features available on ALL the platforms you are targeting.

Building a native app -- that is, using Xcode to build an iOS app and using the Android SDK to build an Android app -- gives you complete access to all of a given platform's specific features and capabilities, thereby ensuring the best user experience on each platform.

This is now my opinion: Native apps are better, simply because they present the user with a native experience -- an experience that will feel familiar to them as a user of the platform. When you choose to use a cross-platform tool you are actively choosing to give your user a less-than-ideal experience on their device, but YOU saved some time (maybe) getting your app to market. Who's the winner?

In my job, my boss and I had a specific conversation about this. We have native iOS and Android apps, on purpose, because we didn't want to give up platform-specific features. We wanted each app to give the best experience it could on its platform. We specifically agreed that a cross-platform solution was not the way we wanted to go.

Comment: Wow great answer. "This is now my opinion: Native apps are better, simply because they present the user with a native experience -- an experience that will feel familiar to them as a user of the platform." -- I wish I'd said that.

Comment: As a point of clarification, specific to Adobe's Flash Platform.  Adobe AIR 3 introduced a way to call Native device code to extend your apps past the APIs exposed through Adobe AIR.  This feature is called Native Extensions; and nulls the argument that Using AIR/Flash Platform does not give "complete access to all of a given platform's specific features and capabilities."

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Interesting indeed. But you're still calling native code, presumably Objective-C for iOS. So you can't get away from Objective-C for native functionality under iOS, which I think supports my point a bit. :-)

Comment: @MarkGranoff I also believe you have to write native extensions for iOS in Objective-C; no other comment though.

Comment: I'd also add that in Air, you have access to a lot of the hardware... just not all of it.  Pretty much anything that is common across platforms (accelerometer, webkit, GPS, etc).  When you need to get at something that isn't exposed via Air, you can write small native extensions (in ObjectiveC or Java) that expose the functionality you care about and then refer to them via your Air app.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you are building, Air is a great platform for developing cross-platform mobile applications.  Despite recent news that the Flash player is no longer being developed for mobile browsers, the native story remains strong.  Plus, having seen native IOS, native Android and Flex development, the Flex platform is much better when it comes to the ease of development.  With high-level features like data binding, visual state management, a solid component/skinning model, transitioning model, etc, it is a generation or two ahead of iOS and Android (IMO).

If you are using Flex for mobile (iOS/Android/Playbook), you get a common look/feel across all mobile devices.  @MarkGranoff suggested that the user experience is downgraded when using an approach, but I'd challenge that.

Although I agree that an out-of-the-box styling of the UI components in Air feels a tad off, I don't recommend that anyone build apps that way anyways.  Instead, create an app that looks like your app.  There have been many applications that don't conform to the native look/feel of iOS or Android but are still quality from an aesthetic and UX perspective.

There is something to be said for an app that looks/behaves the same across all platforms.  I can tell you this much... the user doesn't really care.  If it looks good, feels good and does what they want, they are happy.

The Flex Mobile SDK uses a lot of the same UI paradigms (especially in the soon-to-be-released version of the SDK) and it is getting better.  I wouldn't discredit it.  You can save a lot of money and time using something like Flex Mobile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flex to compile to AIR for iOS or android. 
The performance of AIR vs Objective C or Java is significantly slower. 
The advantage of using AIR is to have one cod base delivered to two platforms. 
But if you have the know-how, Objective C and Java are better suited to development on their respective platforms. However many successful apps have been launched on iOS and Android using AIR. If you want to know if it would work for you I would seek out those apps in iTunes and Android Market and see how they perform for you.
If you app is not a game it will likely work fine. And if you app is a simple game it could also work fine. 
Also remember there are other multi=platform development tools to choose from, like phone gap, or appcellerator:
http://www.appcelerator.com/
http://phonegap.com/

or even Unity 3D:
http://unity3d.com/

UPDATE:
Since this original answer in Novemer 2011, Adobe has made significant improvements to AIR for iOS and Android. Petformance problems are negligible unless you are doign somethign very instinsive such as large image processing. 
Likewise, Unity3D has improved a lot too. It's an excellent choice for games that are 2D or 3D.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Air to develop cross platform apps, you should notice the following facts:

1) you don't have access to native features (but you can use Air Native Extensions to by pass this problem)

2) performance is slower than native apps (but you can use Starling framework to use GPU power in devices which will increases the performance a lot!)

the bottom line is that building mobile apps using AS3 and Flex/Air SDK is the best solution you can think of and the performance if using starling is much higher than native apps!

Answer (score -9):

I don't think you can use Adobe Flex on iOS.  Another cross platform solution to investigate would be HTML5.  If you can afford it, the best solution might be to implement it twice, once with xcode for iOS and once with Android for Android.

Comment: -1 for the incorrect information.  You've been able to use Adobe Flex (and Adobe Flash Platform tools) to build Native iOS Applications for quite some time.  There was a short term snafu with Apple's developer agreements; however Apple changed their licensing and many applications are built w/ Flash tools.  Most recently Macinarium, a Flash built app, was the top of the game charts in iOS.  http://machinarium.net/demo/

Comment: You should check out the Adobe Air